# Elasticsearch - Sort query based on collapse results

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to group/stack items based on their SKU.

Currently if sorting from high to low, an item thats being sold for $10 or $1, will show the $1 item first (because it's also sold for $10 it will be placed in front of the array ofcourse). The sorting should only respect the `lowest_price` for its sorting operation, for only that specific SKU.

Is there a way so I can do sorting based on the lowest_price of for every SKU and only return 1 single item per SKU?

If the results from the collapse could be used as variable for the sorting, this could be solved but I haven't been able to find out how this work.

My item object looks like this:

```
{
    itemId: String,
    sku: String,
    price: Number
}
```

This is my query:

```
let itemsPerPage = 25;

let searchQuery = {
    from: itemsPerPage * page,
    size: itemsPerPage,
    _source: ['itemId'],
    sort: [{'sale.price': 'desc'}],
    query: {
        bool: {
            must: [],
            must_not: []
        }
    },
    collapse: {
        field: 'sku',
        inner_hits: [{
                name: 'lowest_price',
                size: 1,
                _source: ['itemId'],
                sort: [{
                    'price': 'asc'
                }]
            }
        ],
    }
};
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting in above. query looks to be fine

Answer (score 0):

You need to add sort underneeth collapse.
example:

```
GET /test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "constant_score": {
          "filter": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {
              "match" : {
              "job_status" : "SUCCESS"
              }
              }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
   "collapse": {
    "field": "run_id.keyword"
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "@timestamp": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This may solve your issue.